# get all attachment files using ListData.svc

Tags: 2010, list, attachments, listdata.svc

I am trying to get all attachments in a custom list that has been attacht to the all items.
I have used `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList/attachmentFiles` but it returns `the request URI is not valid`. How do I get all attachments in a custom list? I cannot use CSOM or JSOM, because the list is located in different site collection. appreciate all kind of advice. (it is a SharePoint 2010 environment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [SP.ListItem.attachmentFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246450%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property is **not** available in SharePoint 2010.

The following REST query returns all attachments in a List in SharePoint 2010:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Requests?$select=Attachments&$expand=Attachments
```

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the Attachments and ID column and Title column and store it in a in-memory database or download the documents into  file system, along withe metadata .                        
  Any sample code available